# Какие существуют инструменты для отладки Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

Какие инструменты существуют, чтобы исследовать процесс добавления библиотек в проект с помощью gradle? Использую Intelij Idea и одна из библиотек упорно не добавляется в проект, хотя все остальные импортируются без проблем. Библиотека находится в локальном репозитории, и, по идее, проблем быть не должно, либо они не совсем очевидны для меня.
Вкладка build в Idea, к сожалению, не содержит подробной информации по зависимостям, только по таскам.

Comment: Разве нет никаких логов?

Comment: а как вы собственно добавляете локальный репозиторий? Может там собака  зарыта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_logging) список флагов, в том числе дофига про подробный логгинг. Начни с `info` (скорее всего этого будет достаточно), и если что переключись на `debug`, хотя, конечно в логах утонешь.